# JQuery on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image of a product, with a "new product" image on top. When i throw the mouse on top of that, it takes it as if the mouse left the product picture.

Also, when i mouseover, the div that appears should not disappear because the mouse enters that.

Here is the current example:
http://jsfiddle.net/euhcc/8/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/euhcc/9/

I think what you're looking for is `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.

Check the updated fiddle to see if that's what you're looking for.

In jQuery, `mouseleave` examines more of the "area" which is covered by an element and its descendants, rather than the element itself.  That means if you have an element which is presented over the element (in context: `$(this)`), and it is a descendant of `$(this)`, and you want to ensure that the functionality is based on whether the mouse is physically over where the `$(this)` element would occupy (other elements notwithstanding), then use `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are targeting only modern browsers - pointer-events:none;

http://jsfiddle.net/euhcc/10/

```
  <div style="position:absolute; width: 180px; pointer-events:none;">
```

Comment: I did not know such a thing existed - +1

Comment: This does not work if the user wants to mouseover the div sliding up.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.retslet').hide();

        $('.billede_wrap').hover(function(){
           $('.retslet').slideDown("fast");
        },function(){
           $('.retslet').slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
​
```